# MySQL RDS Slave stop replicating

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds

I have a master DB running on internal network and an AWS RDS slave replica from the Master DB. When I upload a fresh copy of the master, the slave will replicate for few days with no issues. After a couple of days, the slave status says its correct but records will be missing on the DB. 
I ran both

```
show master status
```

AND

```
show slave status
```

The Master_log_file and Read_Master_log_Pos are matching. 
**One thing to mention we ran a huge dump on the master daily from a legacy system.**

What could be the reason for the discrepancy  between the two and how to fix it ?

Thanks in Advance.

**Update:** Today we got yesterday data. It is possible that the amount of data we are replicating everyday cause the slave to get clogged and take time to get update ?

**Update 2**

After leaving Slave during the weekend. the Seconds_behind_Master went 
 down to zero. Also here the result of show slave status

`Slave_IO_State:    Waiting for master to send event,
Master_Host:    master_host_url,
Master_User:    replica,
Master_Port:    3306,
Connect_Retry:  60,
Master_Log_File:    mysql-bin.000325,
Read_Master_Log_Pos:    33015975,
Relay_Log_File: relaylog.003679,
Relay_Log_Pos:  54412,
Relay_Master_Log_File:  mysql-bin.000325,
Slave_IO_Running:   Yes,
Slave_SQL_Running:  Yes,
Replicate_Do_DB:    ,
Replicate_Ignore_DB:    ,
Replicate_Do_Table: ,
Replicate_Ignore_Table: mysql.plugin,mysql.rds_monitor,mysql.rds_sysinfo,mysql.rds_replication_status,mysql.rds_history,innodb_memcache.config_options,innodb_memcache.cache_policies,
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:    ,
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:    ,
Last_Errno: ,
Last_Error: ,
Skip_Counter:   ,
Exec_Master_Log_Pos:    33015975,
Relay_Log_Space:    142937,
Until_Condition:    None,
Until_Log_File: ,
Until_Log_Pos:  ,
Master_SSL_Allowed: No,
Master_SSL_CA_File: ,
Master_SSL_CA_Path: ,
Master_SSL_Cert:    ,
Master_SSL_Cipher:  ,
Master_SSL_Key: ,
Seconds_Behind_Master:  ,
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert:  No,
Last_IO_Errno:  ,
Last_IO_Error:  ,
Last_SQL_Errno: ,
Last_SQL_Error: ,
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:    ,
Master_Server_Id:   1,
Master_UUID:    ,
Master_Info_File:   mysql.slave_master_info,
SQL_Delay:  ,
SQL_Remaining_Delay:    ,
Slave_SQL_Running_State:    Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it,
Master_Retry_Count:Master_Bind: 86400,
Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:    ,
Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:   ,
Master_SSL_Crl: ,
Master_SSL_Crlpath: ,
Retrieved_Gtid_Set: ,
Executed_Gtid_Set:  ,
Auto_Position   ,`

Comment: Could it be that some errors are being skipped? Run this please to check: `show variables like "slave_skip_errors";`

Comment: Please provide more details -- such as `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and whether they are the same on both servers.

Comment: @Je I just ran CALL mysql.rds_skip_repl_error; and got "Slave is running normally.  No errors detected to skip."

Comment: @Rick usually when i got table created related error "I can see them on AWS console" with a sign that something is wrong. but currently looks fine  just not replicating. and logs still moving

Comment: That sounds like a dangerous procedure to call without first discovering the cause.  Is it possible to run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on the Slave when the problem happens?  (Probably too late now.)

Comment: @RickJames I have one more month worth of testing before we got live using this infrastructure. I already had ran  `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` before I ran the procedure there is no errors. Also It got yesterday data today.

Comment: There is a significant difference between _not_ getting data vs _delayed_ data.  Which is it?

Comment: I cant say for sure!  I would have to check the slave again tomorrow to see if i am getting todays data or not

Comment: Start debugging with the time lagging between the master and slave. Use mysqldbcompare utility to compare the schema and data. Check binlog format. Also, please mention how do you compare the data(yesterday data). Check whether you skipped any objects on replication. And finally create an simple objects on master and check whether it is replicating on slave machine. Provide these details here, it will be easy for us to understand the issue clearly.

Comment: @rathishDBA I used mysqldbcompare and the consistency test failed. I compare the data by take a very large table on Master and compare last record to the slave table. Finally i created a record on Master it took over 12 hours to get to Slave. So i think taking very long time to get to slave. does this mean the slave it clogged `Seconds_Behind_Master:16994`

Comment: @Zeedia if I am not wrong, slave machine is 12 hours behind master. This is the reason master data is not available immediately on the slave server. There are multiple reason for this issues and there many ways you can reduce the slave lagging. Before we proceed, just provide the SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G output. It will help us to understand the relay log space and how much data currently slave processing and master binary log reading position. If in-case there is no issues with queries/replication, we have to check the network latency. Provide slave status details.

Comment: @rathishDBA question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue is Slave need time to catch up. we stopped migration of the legacy system during the weekend and in the beginning is this week. which lead slave to sync up with Master with no issues.

Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the comments and your update to the question, it looks like the case where the data being loaded from legacy system is taking too long to be applied to the SLAVE.

Without the information on what your `binlog_format` is set to, I can only assume that it is set to `ROW`. You can try setting this to `MIXED` and then the SLAVE updates should run a lot quicker and not lag behind the master unless there are other factors affecting the SLAVE being slow.

When logged in as a privileged user, run the following from MySQL client:

`SET GLOBAL binlog_format='MIXED';`

If the above resolves your problem, then add this to your /etc/my.cnf to make it permanent across MySQL restarts.

Comment: I cant run above command because I am using AWS RDS which do not give super user privileges. I posted the slave status above

Comment: With RDS you should be able to create a Parameter Group and set the value for `binlog_format` in there. Have a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html for details.

Comment: I checked the Parameter Group I am using for the Slave and its set to to 'Mixed'.

Comment: Well in that case can you check if there are any limits on CPU cycles for your RDS instance? I can only assume that the RDS instance is unable to process the volume generated by data load.